# UITest the navigation to "out of app" environment

Tags: ios, settings, xcode-ui-testing

I'm currently making some UITests to my app and I would like to test the behaviour of a "iOS Settings" button I have which (off course) sends the user to the setting,

Is there a way to UITest this?

Answer (score 0):

UI Testing cannot interact with anything outside of your application. In your scenario, the framework can no longer do anything once your app opens Settings.

To verify this, try printing out the app's hierarchy once Settings opens. You will notice that nothing in Settings nor the navigation bar will show up - you will only see your app's information.

```
print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I understand that, my question is more related to know if there's a way to at least check if the app will go to background afterwards or something like that... that at least would check that an extern URL was opened :)